# Loading XML as datasource in java web from root

Tags: java, web

I am doing a java web app and the datasource(another lib) is reading from xml file.

at the moment my code will read from :

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Data\\Data.xml"
```

On debug/run, it will read this folder :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\config
```

The xml file is located at the root of the project files and it works fine with normal java application, it however does not work fine with web app.

How do i alter my code in which it reads from a specific folder on the web root or etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How to read from absolute location**

```
        File file = new File("D:/FolderName/");

        // Getting all files in directory
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }

        // Reading a particular file

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/FolderName/testfile.xml"));
            String line = null;

            while(true)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(line == null)
                    break;

                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(reader != null)
            {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

**How to read from root(web inf ) folder in web applications**

```
      ServletContext sc = session.getServletContext();
      URL url = ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/testdata.xml")
```

> getResource("/WEB-INF/testdata.xml") gives you a URL
>
> getResourceAsStream gives you an input stream
>
> getRealPath gives you the path on disk of the relevant file.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/testdata.xml");
```

OR

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(...);
```

OR

```
context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/testdata.xml");
```

Comment: If i am intending to call vrom RESTFul APi ? how should i do it ?